# mysql - using datediff and sumif for aging analysis. i'm not getting the correct aging data. please check if my query is ok

Tags: mysql

```sql
SELECT t1.CurrencyCode, t1.PartersCode, t2.Name,t1.GuaranteeNoXOL,t1.GuaranteeNo,t1.GuaranteeNo_Grp,t1.TotalAmountExpected,t1.statementdate,
   DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), t1.statementdate) AS days_past_due,
    SUM(IF(DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), t1.statementdate) = 0, t1.TotalAmountExpected, 0)) AS 'Today',
    SUM(IF(DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), t1.statementdate) BETWEEN 1 AND 30, t1.TotalAmountExpected, 0)) AS '1 - 30 Days',
    SUM(IF(DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), t1.statementdate) BETWEEN 31 AND 60, t1.TotalAmountExpected, 0)) AS '31 - 60 Days',
    SUM(IF(DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), t1.statementdate) BETWEEN 61 AND 90, t1.TotalAmountExpected, 0)) AS '61 - 90 Days',
    SUM(IF(DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), t1.statementdate) BETWEEN 91 AND 120, t1.TotalAmountExpected, 0)) AS '91 - 120 Days',
    SUM(IF(DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), t1.statementdate) BETWEEN 121 AND 180, t1.TotalAmountExpected, 0)) AS '121 - 180 Days',
    SUM(IF(DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), t1.statementdate) BETWEEN 181 AND 360, t1.TotalAmountExpected, 0)) AS '181 - 360 Days',
    SUM(IF(DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), t1.statementdate) BETWEEN 361 AND 720, t1.TotalAmountExpected, 0)) AS '1 - 2 Years',
    SUM(IF(DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), t1.statementdate) BETWEEN 721 AND 1080, t1.TotalAmountExpected, 0)) AS '2 - 3 Years',
    SUM(IF(DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), t1.statementdate) BETWEEN 1081 AND 1440, t1.TotalAmountExpected, 0)) AS '3 - 4 Years',
    SUM(IF(DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), t1.statementdate) BETWEEN 1441 AND 1800, t1.TotalAmountExpected, 0)) AS '4 - 5 Years', 
    SUM(IF(DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), t1.statementdate) BETWEEN 1081 AND 2160, t1.TotalAmountExpected, 0)) AS '5 - 6 Years', 
    SUM(IF(DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), t1.statementdate) > 2160, t1.TotalAmountExpected, 0)) AS 'Over 6 Years' FROM debtorsregisterinfo t1
    INNER JOIN partnersinfo t2 ON t2.Id = t1.PartersCode
    WHERE  t1.fullypaid=0 AND t1.exclude=0 AND t1.reversed=0
    GROUP BY t1.PartersCode, t1.CurrencyCode ORDER BY  t2.Name ASC, t1.statementdate DESC;
```

Comment: *i'm not getting the correct aging data* What is the incorrectness?

Comment: SELECT t1.IdKey,t1.fullnames,t1.GuaranteeNo,t1.GuaranteeNo_Grp,t1.GuaranteeNoXOL, t2.Name ,t1.PartersCode,t1.CurrencyCode, t1.TotalAmountExpected AS UNPAID, t1.statementdate,DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), t1.statementdate) AS days_past_due  FROM debtorsregisterinfo t1
LEFT JOIN partnersinfo t2 ON t1.PartersCode = t2.Id
WHERE t1.reversed = 0
AND t1.fullypaid = 0
AND t1.exclude = 0                                                                                                                                            This query gives different totals for a particular record

Comment: Facts and codes must be added into the question text as an update.

Comment: You are, unfortunately, misusing [MySQL's notorious nonstandard GROUP BY implementation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html). It bites pretty much everybody.  Try giving this command before you debug your query. `SET SESSION sql_mode = sys.list_add(@@session.sql_mode, 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY');`. Then the query will fail until you put enough terms in your `GROUP BY` clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that you have added a comment mentioning your "expected" vs "actual" gap is being validated by another query.

If this is the case, It is most likely that you are falling victim to a very common misunderstanding of how `mysql` conducts a `group by` statement.

There is a configuration setting in `mysql config` which enforces "strict" grouping rules. These are lately becoming the default policy.

When grouping, if your select columns are not ALL present in your `group by` statement, then you have a potential for your *intent* to not correctly return. This is because other columns may be `soft grouped` and in this case, mysql engine is converting your select column into `any_value('mycol')`. `any_value('mycol')` will return an **arbitrary** row value from the column based on your filter statement. This means that the resultset retrieved may not be a guaranteed exact match to another execution of the same query, at a different time.

Worse, the result may serendipitously return the resultset you expected, and you may proceed under the false assumption that your query is correct.

To prevent this, either change the mysql configuration flag to enforce strict grouping rules, or always include every `non-aggregate` column from your select statement in your group by statement as well.

That is to say:

```
SELECT t1.CurrencyCode, t1.PartersCode, t2.Name,t1.GuaranteeNoXOL,t1.GuaranteeNo,t1.GuaranteeNo_Grp,t1.TotalAmountExpected,t1.statementdate,
   DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), t1.statementdate) AS days_past_due,
    SUM(IF(DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), t1.statementdate) = 0, t1.TotalAmountExpected, 0)) AS 'Today',
    SUM(IF(DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), t1.statementdate) BETWEEN 1 AND 30, t1.TotalAmountExpected, 0)) AS '1 - 30 Days',
    SUM(IF(DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), t1.statementdate) BETWEEN 31 AND 60, t1.TotalAmountExpected, 0)) AS '31 - 60 Days',
    SUM(IF(DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), t1.statementdate) BETWEEN 61 AND 90, t1.TotalAmountExpected, 0)) AS '61 - 90 Days',
    SUM(IF(DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), t1.statementdate) BETWEEN 91 AND 120, t1.TotalAmountExpected, 0)) AS '91 - 120 Days',
    SUM(IF(DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), t1.statementdate) BETWEEN 121 AND 180, t1.TotalAmountExpected, 0)) AS '121 - 180 Days',
    SUM(IF(DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), t1.statementdate) BETWEEN 181 AND 360, t1.TotalAmountExpected, 0)) AS '181 - 360 Days',
    SUM(IF(DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), t1.statementdate) BETWEEN 361 AND 720, t1.TotalAmountExpected, 0)) AS '1 - 2 Years',
    SUM(IF(DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), t1.statementdate) BETWEEN 721 AND 1080, t1.TotalAmountExpected, 0)) AS '2 - 3 Years',
    SUM(IF(DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), t1.statementdate) BETWEEN 1081 AND 1440, t1.TotalAmountExpected, 0)) AS '3 - 4 Years',
    SUM(IF(DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), t1.statementdate) BETWEEN 1441 AND 1800, t1.TotalAmountExpected, 0)) AS '4 - 5 Years', 
    SUM(IF(DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), t1.statementdate) BETWEEN 1081 AND 2160, t1.TotalAmountExpected, 0)) AS '5 - 6 Years', 
    SUM(IF(DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), t1.statementdate) > 2160, t1.TotalAmountExpected, 0)) AS 'Over 6 Years' FROM debtorsregisterinfo t1
    INNER JOIN partnersinfo t2 ON t2.Id = t1.PartersCode
    WHERE  t1.fullypaid=0 AND t1.exclude=0 AND t1.reversed=0
    GROUP BY t1.PartersCode,t1.CurrencyCode,t2.Name,t1.GuaranteeNoXOL,t1.GuaranteeNo,t1.GuaranteeNo_Grp,t1.TotalAmountExpected,t1.statementdate ORDER BY t2.Name ASC, t1.statementdate DESC;
```

should work

Comment: worked perfectly. Thanks so much for your assistance.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT t1.idkey , t1.CurrencyCode, t1.PartersCode, t2.Name,t1.GuaranteeNoXOL,t1.GuaranteeNo,t1.GuaranteeNo_Grp,t1.TotalAmountExpected,t1.statementdate,
   DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), t1.statementdate) AS days_past_due,
      SUM(CASE 
        WHEN DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), t1.statementdate) = 0 THEN t1.TotalAmountExpected ELSE 0 END) AS 'Today',
        SUM(CASE
        WHEN DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), t1.statementdate) >= 1 AND DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), t1.statementdate) <= 30 THEN t1.TotalAmountExpected ELSE 0 END) AS '1 - 30 Days',
       SUM(CASE
        WHEN DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), t1.statementdate) >= 31 AND DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), t1.statementdate) <= 60 THEN t1.TotalAmountExpected ELSE 0 END) AS '31 - 60 Days',
       SUM(CASE 
        WHEN DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), t1.statementdate) >= 61 AND DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), t1.statementdate) <= 90 THEN t1.TotalAmountExpected ELSE 0 END) AS '61 - 90 Days',
       SUM(CASE 
        WHEN DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), t1.statementdate) >= 91 AND DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), t1.statementdate) <= 120 THEN t1.TotalAmountExpected ELSE 0 END) AS '91 - 120 Days',
       SUM(CASE 
        WHEN DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), t1.statementdate) >= 121 AND DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), t1.statementdate) <= 180 THEN t1.TotalAmountExpected ELSE 0 END) AS '121 - 180 Days',
       SUM(CASE 
        WHEN DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), t1.statementdate) >= 181 AND DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), t1.statementdate) <= 360 THEN t1.TotalAmountExpected ELSE 0 END) AS '181 - 360 Days',
       SUM(CASE 
        WHEN DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), t1.statementdate) >= 361 AND DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), t1.statementdate) <= 720 THEN t1.TotalAmountExpected ELSE 0 END) AS '1 - 2 Years',
       SUM(CASE 
        WHEN DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), t1.statementdate) >= 721 AND DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), t1.statementdate) <= 1080 THEN t1.TotalAmountExpected ELSE 0 END) AS '2 - 3 Years',
       SUM(CASE 
        WHEN DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), t1.statementdate) >= 1081 AND DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), t1.statementdate) <= 1440 THEN t1.TotalAmountExpected ELSE 0 END) AS '3 - 4 Years',
       SUM(CASE 
        WHEN DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), t1.statementdate) >= 1441 AND DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), t1.statementdate) <= 1800 THEN t1.TotalAmountExpected ELSE 0 END) AS '4 - 5 Years',
       SUM(CASE 
        WHEN DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), t1.statementdate) >= 1801 AND DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), t1.statementdate) <= 2160 THEN t1.TotalAmountExpected ELSE 0 END) AS '5 - 6 Years',
       SUM(CASE 
        WHEN DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), t1.statementdate) > 2160 THEN t1.TotalAmountExpected ELSE 0 END) AS 'Over 6 Years'
   FROM debtorsregisterinfo t1
LEFT JOIN partnersinfo t2 ON t1.PartersCode = t2.Id
WHERE t1.reversed = 0
AND t1.fullypaid = 0
AND t1.exclude = 0
GROUP BY t1.idkey, t1.PartersCode, t1.CurrencyCode, t2.Name, t1.GuaranteeNoXOL,t1.GuaranteeNo,t1.GuaranteeNo_Grp,t1.TotalAmountExpected,t1.statementdate,
   DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), t1.statementdate) 
ORDER BY t1.IdKey, t2.Name ASC, t1.statementdate DESC;
```

Comment: Hi Leslie, welcome to SO!

Please review the [best answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) policy to learn how to improve your impact to our community.